# How to make IMPORTXML load the entire page?

Tags: html, xml, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

Im trying to convert the names of prodects in a webpage to a sheets file.
Website: [The Website](https://www.myperfume.co.il/155567-%D7%9B%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%91%D7%A8?order=down_title)

However, you can see that when i scroll to the bottom of the page it loads for a second and then shows me the rest of the products.
When I use the cmd :
`=IMPORTXML(URL, "//*[starts-with(@id, 'item_id')]")`
It generates only the first section of the products(the first section is between the start to the first load).

**How can I generate the whole products?**

Comment: Have you tried using the full xpath when the items are loaded? e.g `full XPATH = /html/body/div[7]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]`

Comment: @DiegoSanchez If I am using the full xpath, what should be the finale importxml command?

Comment: You can use the xpath provided above, which you can do so yourself as well by inspecting the element within the webpage and navigate through the specified `<div>` and copy the full xpath by right clicking on a portion of the HTML

Comment: It gives me an error when i use this xpath